# Can you add separators to Docky?

Tags: docky

Is it possible to add more separators to Docky? If so, how? I've checked through the preferences window but I didn't see anything about adding separators there.

Comment: Too bad.
Docky is a great app, but I'm switching to Cairo-Dock for it's lack of configuration features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Dyer [said earlier this year](https://answers.launchpad.net/docky/+question/95774) in response to the question "How do you Add a Separator line?":

> You dont. There is no way to add these yourself and no plans for such a feature.

He went on to explain:

> Docky is all about simplicity. Being able to add separators gives you no new functionality. You can already arrange/group launchers however you want. That little bit of separation between them really doesn't give you anything worthwhile and we try to keep the feature set somewhat small and not present the user with too many options (we pick what we feel are the 'sane' options).

Comment: Your link is broken. I assume you also meant to link here: https://answers.launchpad.net/docky/+question/95774

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't add separators in Docky.

The developers have [said](https://answers.launchpad.net/docky/+question/95774) that this feature is not planned for future releases either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. :-) But its a little and not very pleasant trick.

1. Simple create a fully transparent PNG with resolution of 32x32 pixels.
2. Create a launcher. Name it "space" or something and assign it an transparent PNG as icon.
3. Launcher will execute something like "echo > /dev/null" which does "nothing" and very quickly.
4. Add new launcher to dock by Drag&Drop

Done. But... This trick has a little problem. When mouse is over this "separator" it will be labeled as "space" (or something you entered in the launcher name).

Works for me very well. :-)

Have a nice day.